# Preventing a file being downloaded or accessed on a server

Tags: php, apache, download

I want to be able to prevent people from accessing a file on a server, such as a document if they were to directly link to it via the URL. This is for security purposes so that documents on the site just can't be stumbled upon and downloaded...

What is the best approach for this?

I've tried using the .htaccess to deny access to docs and txts for examples, but you can still download the files it just prevents you from accessing the directory...which isn't what I want to do.

```
<Files ~ "\.(doc|txt)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: [**See this answer**](http://serverfault.com/a/298771) and replace with your extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in your .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(doc|txt)">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Tried this, still not working - allows me to download the document still

Answer (score 4):

put it in a directory outside the public space and provide it via a custom PHP page which requires login or what you prefer

```
echo file_get_contents(/var/www/example.com/file.txt);
```

should works I guess

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to not put it in the web server's document root in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can in your .htaccess redirect all requests to files in that folder to a special PHP page that only allows logged in users to download the file but denies those unauthorized to access it.

Also it's a good idea putting the target file itself in a folder above `public_html`.